# How do I parse XML results into an array?

Tags: python, xbmc

I'm new to Python and need some help. The web hasn't been very helpful. Simply put, I have a web response that looks like this:

```
<html>
  <field>123</field>
  <field>456</field>
</html>
```

What I'm trying to do is take all of the contents from the field elements into an array that I can index. The end result would look like this:

```
myArray[0] = 123
myArray[1] = 456
```

and so on...

What I'm going to end up doing with this is running a random number generator to randomly pick one of the elements in this array and retrieve its value.

Is this possible? I can't seem to find a straight answer on the web, so I feel like I might be asking for the wrong thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use XPath [Xpath python](http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) to parse the values and just insert them into a list, first declare and empty list `my_list=[]` and then just append the values `my_list.append(parsed_value)`.

Answer (score 8):

If you're doing simple things like that you might want to look at the [ElementTree](http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) module built into python. You don't need to install anything extra, its all included in python

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

filename='data.txt'
tree = ET.parse(filename)
root = tree.getroot()
myArray=[]

for x in root.findall('field'):
    myArray.append(x.text)

print(myArray)
```

Answer (score 2):

By far the easiest way to extract information from HTML is [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/). Here's a snippet to get the list you want:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text)
>>> fields = [int(el.text) for el in soup.find_all("field")]
>>> fields
[123, 456]
```

Since you're new to Python:

1. We `import` the `BeautifulSoup` class from the `bs4` module (which you'll need to install - see the link above).
2. We create a `BeautifulSoup` instance called `soup` from `html_text`.
3. We create a list called `fields`, using a list comprehension:

   - convert the `text` of `el` into an `int`eger
   - `for` each `el`
   - which we get by finding all `field` elements in `soup`

Answer (score -3):

look at standart modules!
http://docs.python.org/2/library/htmlparser.html#examples

if you need this only for the case from question, try this
it replaces all tags with `' '` (space), and `str.split` splits resulted text by one or more spaces as delimeters

```
import re
def get_data(str_data):
    return re.sub(r'<.*?>',' ', str_data).split()

str_data = """<html>
  <field>123</field>
  <field>456</field>
</html>"""

print get_data(str_data) # prints "['123', '456']"
```

*sorry for my English*

Comment: regexes are a [notoriously](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) fragile way to parse HTML ... and this answer relies on there being no other content in the response at all, which seems unlikely.

Comment: @ZeroPiraeus I said `if you need for ONLY THIS CASE`. Of course, RE are bad for xml, but I believe in KISS. If there is simple way to do something, why install monsterous modules?